# Why do iOS app reviews only appear in iTunes but not the App Store

Tags: ios, itunes

I have recently launched my first app on the app store and have since received 2 reviews which appear in iTunes connect and the app store from within iTunes.

However neither of these reviews have made it onto the app store when viewed on an iDevice. The first review was from about 5 days ago if that helps and the app is called Knit Mate

Answer (score 0):

As I reviewed with my `iOS Apps` one of these may be the reason.
As `iOS App` need minimum `5 ratings` to display an average rating in `Appstore` .And Each App store manage review and the rating process separatly.And please ensure the rated store country and the check ?

Comment: It does say that there are too few reviews to give an average but it doesn't show any of them. Even in iTunes (not iTunes Connect) it says there are too few ratings to give an average but it DOES show them... The reviews are from the UK which is also where my account is